# Change dates to a right format in a query of SQLite

Tags: sqlite, date

I have stored dates in a Sqlite database with the following format:

```
21-03-2014, 09:56
```

How I can convert this date a right sqlite format inside a select query? (for ordering them, **ORDER BY *formatted_date***)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've converted dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm into yyyymmddhhmm and I've used it in order clause

```
substr(date,7,4)||substr(date,4,2)||substr(date,1,2)||substr(date,13,2)||substr(date,16,2)
```